# Selecting the top customers from my DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 tables as follows

**sales (table1):**

```
sales_id, userid(buyerid), product id, productname, orderid, status
```

**users (table2):**

```
userid, username, pass
```

Now, I need to display the top customer who makes regular purchase on my shopping site.

How can I achieve this?

I tried as

```
SELECT A.(*), B.username 
FROM sales A, users B
WHERE A.userid=B.userid AND A.status='delivered' LIMIT 10;
```

And also, I need to display records only when there are more than 10 or 15 minimum purchases should be made.

Now, the same has to be looped and shown as top 10 buyers with the username, need to know how to loop too

Need help on this, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join both tables, group them by their `userid` and count the number of records. Try something like this,

```
SELECT  a.userID, a.`username`, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN sales b
            ON a.userid = b.userid
WHERE   b.`status` = 'delivered'
GROUP BY a.userID
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is the left join necessary since he's only interested in actual sales?  Just wondering and maybe a performance hit if he's got alot of users and sales..

Comment: @StevenCheng yes you are correct, i was thinking it another way, like what if he wants to display all userid whether it has bought a product or not, any way i just update the answer. thanks!

Comment: @John Woo  oh yeah, i forgot the main thing, I also want to have to show minimum 10 sales to be made, this was missed... by the way, count should not be like this COUNT(b.*)?

Comment: Its not producing any results

Comment: hi, with the little tweak, its working perfectly now, thanks so much.